# pgfplotstable - Error while transposing a CSV table which is read from disk

Tags: pgfplotstable

I want to read a CSV file from disk and then transpose the table that I read. When I create the table in my document, there is no problem with `pgfplotstabletranspose` command. However, when I try to read the file from the disk, I get an error as

> Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column 'Label' from
>   table 'attachments/paper_survey.csv'. Please check spelling (or
>   introduce name aliases)..

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{% Read the data into a table macro
Label;A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;J;K;L;M;N;O
Yes;0.00;0.20;0.00;0.26;0.11;0.00;;0.49;0.14;0.31;0.03;0.60;0.06;0.06;0.00
No;1.00;0.80;1.00;0.74;0.89;1.00;;0.51;0.86;0.69;0.97;0.40;0.94;0.94;0.00
High;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.26
Medium;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.21
Low;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.53
}\datatable

% \pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon]{attachments/paper_survey.csv}\datatable

\pgfplotstabletranspose[string type,
    colnames from=Label,
    input colnames to=Label
]\datatabletransposed{\datatable}

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: @Raaja I updated my MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem running your data from the attachments subfolder

You may want to check the "G" values since there was an empty yes/no slot and the "O" values are 0

Double check your subfolder/file name are correct since this combination worked for me

mainTeXfolder/attachments/paper_survey.csv

```
Label;A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;J;K;L;M;N;O
Yes;0.00;0.20;0.00;0.26;0.11;0.00;0.0;0.49;0.14;0.31;0.03;0.60;0.06;0.06;0.00
No;1.00;0.80;1.00;0.74;0.89;1.00;0.0;0.51;0.86;0.69;0.97;0.40;0.94;0.94;0.00
High;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.26
Medium;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.21
Low;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.53
```

[image]

Since you did not elect plot method I used your same one from a previous question

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon]{attachments/paper_survey.csv}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstabletranspose[string type, colnames from=Label, input colnames to=Label]\datatabletransposed{\datatable}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked, % Stacked horizontal bars
    xmin=0, % Start x axis at 0
    ytick=data, % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
    yticklabels from table={\datatabletransposed}{Label} % Get the labels from the Label column of the \datatable
]
\addplot [fill=green!70!blue] table [x=Yes, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatabletransposed};
\addplot [fill=red!70!blue] table [x=No, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatabletransposed};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```